# How to work with NOT IN using CTE in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue with using NOT IN with cte. Actually, I want to display also a user who does not have any person_id in AccountOf table. But the statement after NOT IN is not executing Can anyone help me, please?

```
with p as (
        select p.id, p.name, a.person_id, Sum(b.balance) balance
        from persons p
        join accountOf a on a.person_id = p.Id
        join BankAccounts b on b.Id = a.account_id
        group by p.name
    )
    select *
    from p
    where p.balance < (select Max(balance) from p) * 0.5 OR p.id NOT IN (select person_id from p);
```

The 3 tables are:

```
Persons

id | name | address | age | eyeColor | gender

BankAccounts

id | balance

AccountOf

id | person_id → Persons | account_id → BankAccounts
```

Comment: @P.Salmon Can you please help me?

Comment: Which purpose should this with construct have? Could you please show sample input and expected outcome?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: The `p.id NOT IN (select person_id from p)` condition will never be true. (You want persons, not p.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like person_id is not in the p table specified in your subquery. Person_id is in the a table so if you change it to p.id NOT IN (select person_id from account of) that should work so long as the join you’re doing in the CTE between tables p and a is NOT an inner join since that would be filtering for only ids in both tables and would make the filtering out in your subquery redundant.

You also could do this just using subqueries instead of CTE to not use ram (but that is another topic!)

Comment: can you please help me to show a query that works without cte?

Comment: You can just move your where clause in the above query and remove with p as ( )

Comment: still not get it, can you please edit my query so I can get clarity?Thanks

Comment: sure - but your problem is with the joins and how you are referencing the ids to join on not the cte itself.  ```select sub.id, sub.name, sub.person_id, sub.balance 
from (
select p.id, p.name, a.person_id, Sum(b.balance) balance
from persons p
inner join BankAccounts b on p.id = b.id
where p.id NOT IN (SELECT person_id from AccountOf)
group by p.id, p.name, a.person_id
) as sub
where sub.balance < (select max(sub.balance) from sub)```